# How to tell systemctl to automatically unmount a drive if it's idle and remove directory after unmounting?

Tags: fstab, udisks, systemd-mount

I have this entry in fstab:

```
LABEL=cache /disks/cache ext4 rw,user,x-mount.mkdir,relatime,noauto,errors=remount-ro,x-systemd.idle-timeout=120min  0 0
```

What I expoect to do is:

1. to mount the disk with the label cache on /disks/cache any time I demand it
2. to create the path /dsisks/cache if it doesn't exist
3. To give +rwx permission to my user or any user in it's deffect
4. to atomatically unmount the disk if it's idle after 1 hour

Why step 4 which is isn't working and how to make that the folder be removed after unmounting, is it there a x-umount.rmdir option?

Comment: You should try autofs instead of fstab.  It does exactly this.

Comment: @user10489 are you sure there-s no way to do it with fstab? Because I don't want to over complicate it plus why if not is option 4 already specified?

Comment: Yes, autofs is the only way to automatically mount and unmount.  fstab either mounts once at boot or it mounts manually, it does not handle automatic on demand mounts.  Only autofs does that.

Comment: So then, for what is a do nothing function written on the man then?

Comment: I'm sorry I am unable to parse any meaning from that.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can't be done in fstab.

The following are the typical ways to mount disks:

- Add them to fstab so they are automatically mounted at boot.  (The option `defaults` or `auto` in fstab does this.)
- Mount them manually, either as root with all parameters specified,  or manually as only a mount point or device with remaining options from fstab, or as a user for entries listed in fstab with the `noauto,user` options in the fourth column.
- Use udisks to automatically mount hot insert disks, such as cdroms and usb sticks, usually on the `/media` directory.  This however, only unmounts on user demand.  Udisks typically mounts on device insertion, but it can also be triggered from the command line.
- Use autofs to mount them on demand, when the directory is referenced, and unmount them after a timeout and they are no longer in use.

Autofs is configured by listing managed top directories one per line in `/etc/auto.master` with a config file per managed directory, with each config file listing subdirectories of the managed directories.

For example, auto.master may list `/etc/auto.misc` which in turn may list a number of filesystems or devices with potential filesystems.  The default auto.misc that comes with autofs lists `floppy` (commented out by default) which would be mounted on `/misc/floppy` if it was accessed and a filesystem was available on that device.

Sample lines from auto.master:

```
/misc  /etc/auto.misc
/home  /etc/auto.home
/disks  /etc/auto.disks   --timeout=3600
```

Sample line from auto.misc:

```
floppy         -fstype=auto            :/dev/fd0
```

Sample line from auto.home:

```
someuser         homeserver:/export/home/someuser
```

Autofs can do everything you asked for except set the permissions, which typically are inherited from the permissions of the root directory on the mounted filesystem, or mount options if the filesystem supports that.  The above (untested) disks line would require a corresponding `/etc/auto.disks` file describing the filesystems you want mounted in `/disks/`

Answer (score 0):

Create a per-device automount file via `systemd`. To do so, create a file `/etc/systemd/system/diskname.automount` with the following content:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Automountaje de discos de usuario
After=blockdev@dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-cch.target

[Automount]
Where= mountpoint
TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Replace mountpoint with the desired location and be sure that that location is correctly assigned to an unit drive in `/etc/fstab`.

It should work straight forward.